# Angular $http.put issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have an issue with $http.put using angular.
I have one form that I want to edit, when I click on edit button I send all data on another form, then I edit those data, then I want those data to save when I click save button.

My code to get data from the form:

```
.controller("editTaskCtrl", function($scope, $http){

$scope.editTask = function(value) {
    $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://46.101.203.23:8080/pomomanage-1.0.0/rest/tasks/' + value
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $('#editedId1').val(response.data.id);
            $('#titleToEdit1').val(response.data.title);
            $('#contentToEdit1').val(response.data.content);
            $('#editedStatus1').val(response.data.status);
            $('#editedEstimation1').val(response.data.estimation);              
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("try again");
          });
}
```

})

And my code to save those data:

```
.controller("saveEditedTask", function($scope, $http){
$scope.editedTask = function() {
        $http.put("http://46.101.203.23:8080/pomomanage-1.0.0/rest/tasks/edit", {
            'id': $scope.editedId,
            'title': $scope.editedTitle,
            'content': $scope.editedContent,
            'status': $scope.editedStatus,
            'estimation': $scope.editedEstimation
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            alert("task is edited");
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("try again");
          })
}
```

})

And this is the form i send data:

```
        <form ng-submit="editedTask();" data-ng-controller="saveEditedTask">
            <input type="text" id="editedId1" ng-model="editedId" hidden>
            <input type="number" id="editedEstimation1" ng-model="editedEstimation" hidden>
            <input type="text" id="editedStatus1" ng-model="editedStatus" hidden>
            <label for="editedTitle">Title:</label><input id="titleToEdit1" type="text" ng-model="editedTitle">
            <label for="editedContent">Content:</label><input id="contentToEdit1" type="text" ng-model="editedContent">
            <button type="submit" id="saveEditedTask">Save</button>
        </from>
```

But when i click save button, it returns null data. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: while posting data your property should have `taskToEdit` object the property name like  `$scope.taskToEdit.editedId`

Comment: I just edited the form.

Comment: `editedContent` value must be passing? could you confirm that?

Comment: When you say 'it returns null data', what is returning?  Is the semicolon in ng-submit="editedTask()" expression causing an issue?

Comment: it returns nothing at all, i'm just getting this error: 500 (Internal Server Error), and i'm getting that alert("try again")